# What is the terminal command to show desktop?

Tags: command-line, xfce, xubuntu, xfce-panel

In Xubuntu 13.04 there is a Show Desktop panel plugin.

I'd like to make a keyboard shortcut for this functionality.

How can I activate Show Desktop with a terminal command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah, found it for Xubuntu! No terminal command is needed.

The shortcut is in Settings Manager > Window Manager > Keyboard.

[image: Window Manager screenshot]

Originally I was only looking in Settings Manager > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts, thinking I needed to know the terminal command to use Show Desktop to apply it to a keyboard shortcut, but looks like I don't need to know the terminal command after all.

Thank you for your help, sorry for the confusion~

Answer (score 3):

There is a tutorial which can be found at http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-show-desktop-from-command-line.html

This allows you to command line any key strokes like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or whatever keystrokes you want.

I believe that there may be a better way, I'll keep looking...

Nothing yet....